# int... slots in java convert to list in scala

Tags: scala

Hoi , I think that `int...slots` in java is the same as `slots:Int*` in scala

but how can I use slots in scala now ? Is it a list now ? If slots =2 now, can I do:

```
for(s <-slots
    if s > 8
) println(s)
```

how can I get each element in slots?

Thanks

Comment: please format and clarify your question

Answer (score 4):

It's a `Seq[Int]` in scala. You can use the loop you've got or all of the methods in Seq map, foreach, filter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`slots: Int*` in Scala is *not* the same as `int... slots` in Java. The former is a Seq while the latter is an array

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html for the available methods

Comment: An array is mutable, the Seq is not

Comment: Seq is just the variable's type. Kicking it around in REPL reveals that it's a mutable.WrappedArray underneath. I think making the variable a Seq is a good idea because monkeying around with the parameters of the method like that is very unscala like.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) like others have said.  It can be iterated upon or items can be referenced by index (although I wouldn't recommend that because you can't be sure how many items it has!).

```
def someMethod(slots:Int*) = {
  println(slots(1)) //reference an index
  for(slot<-slots)  //iterate over them
    println(slot)
}
```

Check the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) for other ways you can use it.